# Particles.js moving towards the user on a 3D canvas

Tags: html, canvas, particles.js

I've got Particles.js working on my website as a background however i'm wanting the particles to move forward, towards the user as well as side to side so it's a 3D canvas instead of a 2D canvas, is this possible ?

I was thinking about using transform for the z-index but i can't seem to get it working and even then i imagine it'l make the entire particle canvas move forward not the particles themselves.

Any help is great thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at this effect. Credits goes to https://codepen.io/Sonick/

https://codepen.io/Sonick/pen/HDngF

// OLD ANSWER

I don't know if it is possible inside this plugin, but perhaps this is what will satisy your needs: https://codepen.io/prowseed/pen/yGjgBq

```
/* SCSS */

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: black;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1400px);
  }
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.bubble-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center center;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  opacity: .7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: move 3s infinite;

}

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .bubble:nth-child(#{$i}){
     $size: random(30)+px;
     height: $size;
     width: $size;
     animation-delay: -$i * .2s;
     transform: translate3d( (random(1000) * 1px),  (random(1000) * 1px), (random(2000) * -1px));
     background: hsl( random(360) , 70%, 50%);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bubble-wrap">
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
  <div class="bubble"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is similar to what i'm wanting actually but i wouldn't even know where to start in terms of combining the two, the best example i can find is this section of a Youtube video https://youtu.be/J0RnPKdk7Hg?t=569

However it's barely visible and not the best example ever

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible using only particle.js plugin based on their documentation